# How can I open read-only webpage on Flutter App

Tags: flutter

Can you show me the right way to solve my problem?
I want to run a webpage in the application and disable the screen response to user actions. (read only)

I run the page using the code:

```
String _url = 'https://google.com
await launch(
             _url,
             enableJavaScript: true,
             forceWebView: true,
             forceSafariVC: true,
)
```

But I can't cope with making this page insensitive to user actions (buttons, zooming, etc.). I've tried:

1. Enable "launch" in ignoring or absorbing. Did not work.
2. I tried to run a URL as a background and then put an inactive transparent button on it. I failed to.

I have no idea how to bite it.

Comment: What do you mean my "Enable launch in ignoring or absorbing."? url_launcher will open the link in the browser, right? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

use webview_flutter instead it gives you more control over the web screen